# gst-launch to demux an RTMP stream

Tags: gstreamer, rtmp, gst-launch

I'm using the latest stable version of gstreamer and all plugins, and when I try to play and rtmp stream using this pipeline:

```
gst-launch-0.10 rtmpsrc location='rtmp://server/app/stream flashver=MediaMagic' ! flvdemux name=d d. ! queue ! decodebin ! xvimagesink d. ! queue ! aacparse ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink
```

the pipeline keeps preparing but never starts playing.
However I can play only audio, or only video with these pipelines:

1.

```
gst-launch-0.10 rtmpsrc location='rtmp://flash3.todostreaming.es/radiovida/mobile flashver=MediaMagic' ! flvdemux name=d d. ! queue ! decodebin ! xvimagesink
```

2.

```
gst-launch-0.10 rtmpsrc location='rtmp://flash3.todostreaming.es/radiovida/mobile flashver=MediaMagic' ! flvdemux name=d d. ! queue ! aacparse ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink`
```

What am I missing to play both simultaneourly, audio and video ?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the single quotes in file path.